# Fix API Problem 'AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401' in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am facing this error:

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401

After trying to login to react app, while my exploring on similar solutions I found some answer tell because there is no headers in axios, but I included them and no effect.
I have a Login service to manipulate the API data shown below

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_BASE_URL = 'http://accrdet.localhost';

export default class LoginServices {
    login(username, password) {
        return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/auth/login`, {
            username,
            password
        },
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        }
            ).then(response => {
            if (response.data.accessToken) {
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            }
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    
    logout() {
        return axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/auth/logout`, {}).then(response => {
            if (response.data.accessToken) {
                localStorage.removeItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data))
            }
            return response.data;
        })
    }

    geCurrentUser(){
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    }
}
```

and my login component is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LoginService from '../../services/LoginServices';

const auth_service = new LoginService()

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
        this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            username: "",
            password: ""
        };
    }

    onChangeUsername(e) {
        this.setState({
            username: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePassword(e) {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value
        });
    }

    // Login handler
    handleLogin(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        auth_service.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(
            (response) => {
                const token = response.key;
                const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
                localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
                console.log(`Token: ${token}`);
            }, error => {
                console.log(`Eoor -> ${error}`);
            }
        )
    }


    render() {
        return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin} className="form-signin mt-3">
                <div className="from-control">
                    <label htmlFor="usenrame">Username</label>
                    <input type="text"
                           value={this.state.username}
                           onChange={this.onChangeUsername}
                           name="usenrame"
                           id="username"
                           className="form-control mb-2"
                           placeholder="username"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="from-control">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password"
                           value={this.state.password}
                           onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                           name="password"
                           id="password"
                           className="form-control mb-2"
                           placeholder="********" required
                    />
                </div>
                <button className="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-5 mb-1" type="submit">Sign in</button>
           </form>

        </>
        );
    }
}

export default Login;
```

I would like someone clarfiy how to avoid such problem, where the api working probably on Postman.
Also I need to know how to define the token to pass it in 'authorization': `bearer + access_token`

Answer (score 0):

To pass the headers and data in the axios here is the sample code for which call the rest API and get the authorization code from the backend :

```
login () {
        
            const headers = {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            };

            const credentials = {
              "username" : this.email,
              "password" : this.password
            };

            const loginUrl = process.env.API_BASE_URL+"login";

            this.isLoading  = true;
            axios.post(loginUrl, credentials,{ headers })
                .then((response)  => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    localStorage.token = response.data.token;
                    // redirect user to dashboard
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
            });
      }
```

Now after login you are having your authorization token that you can pass to other APIs. Here is the sample demo code for that :

```
getBrands (page = null) {

            const headers = {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.token
            };

            const url = process.env.API_BASE_URL+"brands?page="+page;
            this.isLoading = true;
            axios.get(url,{ headers })
                .then((response)  => {
                    // store the response in your state 
                    // perform next action according to your logic
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    console.log(error)
                });
      }
```